# How to write these golang and mgo code

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

> My mongodb data is here

```
 db.user.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":1,"NoOfUsers":{"$size":"$user"},"NoOfSales":{"$size":"$sales"},"user":1,"sales":1}}]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"),
    "user" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "chetan",
            "lastName" : "kumar",
            "age" : 23
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "nepolean",
            "lastName" : "dang",
            "age" : 26
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Raj",
            "lastname" : "kumar",
            "age" : 26
        }
    ],
    "sales" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "ashu",
            "lastName" : "jha",
            "age" : 27
        }
    ],
    "NoOfUsers" : 3,
    "NoOfSales" : 1
}
```

> I try to write these code in golang , here is my golang code

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
        "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)
type User struct{
    FIRSTNAME   string      `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LASTNAME    string      `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    AGE     int     `json:"age" bson:"age"`
}
type Sales struct{
    FIRSTNAME   string      `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LASTNAME    string      `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    AGE     int     `json:"age" bson:"age"`
}

type Details struct{
    ID  bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    USER    []User      `json:"user" bson:"user"`
    SALES   []Sales     `json:"sales" bson:"sales"`
}
func detail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }else{
                fmt.Println("dial")
        }
        defer session.Close()


        session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

        c := session.DB("userdb").C("user")


       var result []Details


    o1 := bson.M{"$project":bson.M{"_id":1,"NoOfUser":bson.M{"$size":"$user"},"user":1,"NoOfSales":bson.M{"$size":"$sales"},"sales":1,},}

        operations := []bson.M{o1}
    pipe := c.Pipe(operations)
    err = pipe.All(&result)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        res1B, _ := json.Marshal(result)
        fmt.Fprintf(w,string(res1B))
}

func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/detail",detail)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9080", router))

}
```

> After executing this code my result is like this

```
[{"_id":"57307906f051147d5317984e","user":[{"firstName":"chetan","lastName":"kumar","age":23},{"firstName":"nepolean","lastName":"dang","age":26},{"firstName":"Raj","lastName":"","age":26}],"sales":[{"firstName":"ashu","lastName":"jha","age":27}]}]
```

> Problem is ,it does not show the **NoOfusers** and **NoOfsales** ,So is this possible to print the same output as present in above mongodb result
>   without using any extra struct field like NoOfusers or NoOfsales

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the result without any mapping from `Details` struct, then replace `var result []Details` with `var result []bson.M`.

If you want to map into `Details`, then you need to add a struct for the two fields into `Details`.